# Search for a character within a Python string and then modify subsequent character

Tags: python, string, replace, split

I need to be able to find an asterisk in a Python string, and then run the `upper` method on the *subsequent* character in that string. So suppose I have:

```
s*tring
```

I need to turn it into:

```
sTring
```

Comment: You can iterate over the characters with 'for c in my_string'.

Comment: Where is your code, and what precisely is the problem with it? You can't change strings in-place, they're immutable, so you'll have to create a new one. And what should happen if there's more than one asterisk? I'd probably start by splitting on `'*'`, FWIW.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, why do you think splitting is a better option when there are multiple `'*'`. Isn't using regex a better approach?

Comment: @SilentMonk it's a *different* one, I don't know about *better*. The fact appears to be, though, that the OP hasn't tried either, or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though iteration over the characters of the String and replace is possible it is more efficient to make use of pattern matching. You can do this by `re` module's `sub()` method. Start by defining a lambda function to carry out the conversion process and then match and replace using `re.sub()` with this function. Hope this helps!

```
import re
txt = "s*tring"
callback = lambda pat: pat.group(0).replace("*", "").upper()
txt = re.sub("\*[a-z]", callback, txt)
print txt
```

Result:

```
>> python main.py
sTring
```

Remember this can used for sentences as well.. setting `txt = "My *name is *c.*swadhikar"`

Result:

```
>> python main.py
My Name is C.Swadhikar
```

Comment: What is the use of creating a lambda function if you are gonna give a name to it? `re.sub(<>,lambda pat:....,<>)` should be enough, right?

Comment: @SilentMonk: Thats a valid argument.. Agreed! I have come up with lambda in separate line to make it easier to read and could probably be reused somewhere else in this program later.. Thanks for highlighting!

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, although I've had to make a slight change to accommodate Unicode characters: `output = re.sub("\*\w", lambda pat: pat.group(0).replace("*", "").upper(), input, flags=re.UNICODE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it a brute force way like this:

```
def str_upper(string):

    my_list = list(string)

    indexes = []
    for char in my_list:

        if char is "*":
            indexes.append(my_list.index(char))
            my_list.remove(char)

    result = []
    for i, letter in enumerate(my_list):

       if i in indexes:
          result.append(letter.upper())

       else:
           result.append(letter)

    return "".join(result)
```

Output:

```
>>> str_upper("s*tring")
sTring

>>> str_upper("s*tri*ng")
sTriNg
```

This is also a much shorter pythonic solution:

```
def str_upper2(string):

    return "".join(s[0].upper() + s[1:] for s in string.split('*'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've adapted the Pythonic solution a little, as it fails if the asterisk is the first character of the string: `"".join(s[0].upper() + s[1:] for s in filter(None, input.split("*")))`

Comment: Hmm, there's a slight bug in the Pythonic solution, actually. It always capitalises the first letter. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Yeah I think using `split()` in this case is dangerous, as its hard to tell which letters to capitalize. I think the first solution handles this pretty well, even though its longer, but it's more accurate and won't fail.